# What does "all malt" mean?

Tags: terminology

Pork Slap beer indicates that it's "all malt" in the way that implies an official distinction.  What does "all malt" indicate, assuming there's a standard requirement to use the term accurately.

[image]

Comment: Is this the first [freehand circle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/188984) on this site?

Comment: In the case of Japan, alcoholic beverages are taxed depending on their malt content which has resulted in a slew of beer-like beverages with varying degrees of less malt, or even no malt. These are known here as 発泡酒 "happoushu" rather than "beer". One result of this is that all malt beers are now a premium product so proudly declare their maltiness in their packaging and advertising much like on the can you've pictured.

Answer (score 12):

All malt beer is made entirely from mashed barley malt and without the addition of adjuncts, sugars or additional fermentables.

From an expert of a widely known brand beer producer in my country (Turkey), beers here must be at least 60% malt (This may be different in other countries). The rest are adjuncts, like sugar or corn or rice etc. Using adjuncts is also for decreasing the cost or to lighten the color of beer.

Comment: Where does 60% come from?  I've never heard that specification before.  Is that just with adjuncts or all fermentables (e.g., honey)?

Comment: May be I must make it clear. That knowledge is from a local expert of a big brand in my country. Probably it may be changed. You are right, it is better to make it clear.

Answer (score 4):

Many large brewers, like AB InBev's famous Budweiser line, Miller-Coors' flagship brands and other Standard American Lagers (BJCP Style 1B) use adjunct grains in their grain bill.

> **Aroma:** Little to no malt aroma, although it can be grainy, sweet or corn-like if present. Hop aroma may range from none to a light, spicy or floral hop presence. Low levels of yeast character (green apples, DMS, or fruitiness) are optional but acceptable. No diacetyl.
>
> **Appearance:** Very pale straw to medium yellow color. White, frothy head
>   seldom persists. Very clear.
>
> **Flavor:** Crisp and dry flavor with some low levels of grainy or
>   corn-like sweetness. Hop flavor ranges from none to low levels. Hop
>   bitterness at low to medium-low level. Balance may vary from slightly
>   malty to slightly bitter, but is relatively close to even. High levels
>   of carbonation may provide a slight acidity or dry "sting." No
>   diacetyl. No fruitiness.
>
> **Mouthfeel:** Light body from use of a high percentage of adjuncts such
>   as rice or corn. Very highly carbonated with slight carbonic bite on
>   the tongue.
>
> **Overall Impression:** Very refreshing and thirst quenching.
>
> **Comments:** Strong flavors are a fault. An international style including
>   the standard mass-market lager from most countries.
>
> **Ingredients:** Two- or six-row barley with high percentage (up to 40%)
>   of rice or corn as adjuncts.

Some beers bill themselves as a "Pale Ale", like Rolling Rock also use adjuncts, like rice.  This notation is designed to set them apart from those other beers.  It should be noted that the BJCP guidelines for a Pale Ale are:

> **Aroma:** Usually moderate to strong hop aroma from dry hopping or late
>   kettle additions of American hop varieties. A citrusy hop character is
>   very common, but not required. Low to moderate maltiness supports the
>   hop presentation, and may optionally show small amounts of specialty
>   malt character (bready, toasty, biscuity). Fruity esters vary from
>   moderate to none. No diacetyl. Dry hopping (if used) may add grassy
>   notes, although this character should not be excessive.
>
> **Appearance:** Pale golden to deep amber. Moderately large white to
>   off-white head with good retention. Generally quite clear, although
>   dry-hopped versions may be slightly hazy.
>
> **Flavor:** Usually a moderate to high hop flavor, often showing a citrusy
>   American hop character (although other hop varieties may be used). Low
>   to moderately high clean malt character supports the hop presentation,
>   and may optionally show small amounts of specialty malt character
>   (bready, toasty, biscuity). The balance is typically towards the late
>   hops and bitterness, but the malt presence can be substantial. Caramel
>   flavors are usually restrained or absent. Fruity esters can be
>   moderate to none. Moderate to high hop bitterness with a medium to dry
>   finish. Hop flavor and bitterness often lingers into the finish. No
>   diacetyl. Dry hopping (if used) may add grassy notes, although this
>   character should not be excessive.
>
> **Mouthfeel:** Medium-light to medium body. Carbonation moderate to high.
>   Overall smooth finish without astringency often associated with high
>   hopping rates.
>
> **Overall Impression:** Refreshing and hoppy, yet with sufficient
>   supporting malt.
>
> **Comments:** There is some overlap in color between American pale ale and
>   American amber ale. The American pale ale will generally be cleaner,
>   have a less caramelly malt profile, less body, and often more
>   finishing hops.
>
> **History:** An American adaptation of English pale ale, reflecting
>   indigenous ingredients (hops, malt, yeast, and water). Often lighter
>   in color, cleaner in fermentation by-products, and having less caramel
>   flavors than English counterparts.
>
> **Ingredients:** Pale ale malt, typically American two-row. American hops,
>   often but not always ones with a citrusy character. American ale
>   yeast. Water can vary in sulfate content, but carbonate content should
>   be relatively low. Specialty grains may add character and complexity,
>   but generally make up a relatively small portion of the grist. Grains
>   that add malt flavor and richness, light sweetness, and toasty or
>   bready notes are often used (along with late hops) to differentiate
>   brands.

Comment: Just FYI Rolling Rock is not a pale ale; they self-describe the beer as an "xtra pale lager," and in regards to BJCP styles most closely fits 1A - Lite American Lager although certain elements of the beer would fit in 1B - Standard American Lager.

Comment: Rolling Rock doesn't bill itself as a Pale Ale... it is an American Standard Lager and is often cited for its corn flavor.

Answer (score 0):

The only fermentable sugars are from malt, 2 row North American barley and English crystal malt in the case of this beer. So as others have stated no adjuncts are added. This beer does add ginger for flavoring